# Expression matching Ocaml

Tags: pattern-matching, expression, ocaml, unused-variables

My question is simple: how do I translate this C code :

```
if (x == y + 1)
  // some code
else if (x == y - 1)
  // some code
else if (x == y + 2)
   ....
```

Basically I was thinking of using pattern matching which seemed to be appropriate. Unfortunatly a pattern like this doesn't work:

```
match x with
| y + 1 -> some code
| y - 1 -> some code
| y + 2 -> some code
| _ -> some code
```

The compiler doesn't seem to be happy and from what I have found out, expressions on pattenr matching like I did are not tolerated. Therefore I tried putting them in values thusly:

```
let v1 = y + 1 in
let v2 = y - 1 in
let v3 = y + 2 in
match x with
| v1 -> some code
| v2 -> some code
| v3 -> some code
| _ -> some code
```

Unfortunatly I get warnings saying that my values v1 v2 and v3 are unused and that the the match cases that use them are unused too.

How can I properly match a expression with other expressions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, your C code is almost valid OCaml code.

```
if x = y + 1 then
  (* some code *)
else if x = y - 1 then
  (* some code *)
else if x = y + 2 then
   ....
```

Pattern matching is not a replacement for `if then`, it has a completly different purpose. OCaml allows you to construct types such as `type 'a option = None | Some of 'a` and pattern matching should be used to deconstruct those types. It sould not be used for other purposes.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to say, but to be pedantic, pattern matching _is_ a replacement for `if`, in the sense that `if` is simply convenient syntactic sugar for a two-way match over a Boolean.

Answer (score 2):

If you insist on using a `match` you can use

```
match x with
| z when z=y+1 -> ...
| z when z=y-1 -> ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Thomash is right, this code is naturally expressed by `if` expressions in OCaml, not by patterns. The reason your examples don't work is that patterns consist of constants and *newly-defined* variables. If a variable (a name) appears in a pattern, it becomes a newly defined name whose value is the corresponding part of the match expression. Any previous definition of the name is not relevant inside the match.

If you absolutely had to use a `match`, you could write as follows:

```
match y - x with
| -1 -> (* some code *)
| 0 -> (* some code *)
| 1 -> (* some code *)
| 2 -> (* some code *)
| _ -> (* some code *)
```

But I'm with Thomash, I think `if` expressions would be better here.